# How to install 2 Graphics drivers, and have Ubuntu detect and load which one (without conflict)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics, vga

Originally I wanted to make a live CD with this... However I gave up on that.

So Is there a way to do this, have ubuntu figure out which card is loaded, before loading a driver.
Or... How could I create a script to load at boot to "| grep pci... etc" and print for variable to run "activate_AMD.sh" or "activate_NV.sh" etc...

Comment: Seems this is stil valid? https://askubuntu.com/questions/892532/nvidia-card-for-cuda-and-amd-card-for-display-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu automatically detects which GPU is installed in your machine. If you want a script to switch between Nvida and Intel drivers I've found one you can modify here: [bauca/graphics-switcher](https://github.com/bauca/graphics-switcher/blob/master/Graphics-Switcher)

It will require the program `glxinfo` which you can get by installing:

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

One key function in the bash script that will interest you is this one:

```bash
function CheckForCurrentVideoCardInUse {
    local _VIDEO_CARD=`glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"`
    if [[ $_VIDEO_CARD == *"NVIDIA"* && $_VIDEO_CARD == *"GeForce"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_VIDEO_CARD="NVIDIA"
    elif [[ $_VIDEO_CARD == *"Intel"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_VIDEO_CARD="INTEL"
    else
        ErrorHandler
    fi
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to handle AMD unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry I dont get on this site often enough - But useful information; However, Seems I must clarify.
# Not your fault tho.